# Docker: Nginx doesn't run if I declare volumes in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to run nginx as a container in docker using docker-compose but unfortunately, I'm not able to run it properly.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
 webserver:
  container_name: webserver
  hostname: webserver
  image: nginx
  ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
  volumes:
   - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
```

and here is the error:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2021/01/18 19:04:26 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I've used both relative and absolute paths in volumes but none of them worked. If I have the directory available on the host, it won't work. If I don't have the directory in the host, when I run docker-compose up, it will create an empty directory for nginx in the host but it will be left empty.

Any ideas what's wrong with my setup?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of your host `./nginx` folder?

Comment: run it in interactive mode and check if the directory is being mapped properly and the `nginx.conf` file is available at the specified path.

Comment: @Spirit once I tried with an empty ./nginx directory and it didn't work. I then removed in order to be made via docker-compose, this time, docker created it but with the same error. It was empty

Comment: if you tried with an empty nginx dir its normal it failled.. your `.nginx/` should have a `nginx.cong` without you will have `open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed`.

Comment: @Faisal I ran this command docker run -v /home/invoice-app/server/nginx/:/etc/nginx/ -it nginx /bin/bash and when I check the /etc/nginx inside container, it's empty

Comment: @DrClaw I did this without even creating ./nginx directory as well. Isn't it supposed to create this directory on the host from the container?

Comment: it will create it .. go inside the container and do `touch /etc/nginx/onefile`, exit the container and you will have onefile in nginx even if you didn't have the the nginx dir when you did the `docker-compose up`

Comment: @Faisal When I create the container without specifying -v switch (docker run -it nginx /bin/bash), it works and inside /etc/nginx is the conf files and ... The problem is with mounting I guess...

Comment: But why do you want to mount ./nginx to /etc/nginx ?

Comment: @DrClaw Yes! You are right. If I create a file inside the container, it will be created inside Nginx in the host as well. But, my question is, should I create all config files inside the Nginx directory manually? Isn't there any way to tell docker to copy all these files from the container image inside this mounted directory on the host? My purpose of mounting is to change configs and keep them for a time when for any reason the container crashes or ...

Comment: whenever you map a directory in a container or a non existent one, the directory contents inside are removed or overridden by the contents of the directory on the local machine, i.e if the local directory is empty/non existent it will delete all files inside container and if it contains any file they will be added or replaced inside container.

Comment: @Faisal I was following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71 is it misleading?

Comment: No its not cause under the heading `The Setup` the author created `data/nginx/app.conf` file and saved it locally, which would then have been mounted into the container on startup.

Comment: @Faisal Oh, I see now. I didn't pay attention to this part. Thank you for helping me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No don't try to modify all the confs manually in the containers itself.

Nginx have `/etc/nginx/conf.d` for that so mount your customs confs inside.

Example:

You current directory shouldl look like this:

```
.
├── conf
│   └── custom.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
└── html
    └── index.html
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d # custom conf goes here
      - ./html:/tmp              # custom html goes here
```

I just put the html inside "/tmp" for showing you that my custom config works ..

**./conf/custom.conf**

```
server {
    listen     80;
    location / {
            root /tmp/;
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

**./html/index.html**

```html
<h1>nginx custom conf</h1>
```

Then

```bash
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "nginx_default" with the default driver
Creating nginx_nginx_1 ... done

$ curl localhost
<h1>nginx custom conf</h1>
```